# Evaluate the series of function

Tags: real-analysis

Evaluate the sum $\sum \left({x-7 \over x+1}\right)^n$ for $x\ne -1$

My attempt: If it is just a series, i would get $$\sum_0^\infty \left({x-7 \over x+1}\right)^n = {x+1 \over 8}$$ But it is a series of the function, so how I do evaluate that?

Comment: Infinite geometric series with common ratio???? Also your formula is valid only for $$\Big|\dfrac{x-7}{x+1}\Big|\lt 1,\,\,\,\,x\not=1.$$

Comment: It should be $x \ne -1$ in the question, I just edited! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

evaluate

$\sum y^n$

set 
$y= ({{x-7}\over {x+1}})$

Done.

Comment: Would you elaborate more?

Comment: Sum of geometric progression

Comment: @BigM Do i just have to apply the sum of geometric progression?

Comment: Yes.$\sum_{k=0}^\infty a^k=1/(1-a)$ provided $-1<a<1$

Comment: Thanks! @BigM what would you say about my answer?

Comment: @BigM so the answer is just $(x+1)\over 8$ ? Thanks!